# How to create table in another schema SSMS

Tags: sql-server, ssms, adventureworks

I have created a table in `Person` schema in AdventureWorks2012 with sql query. But I don't know how to do this with SSMS wizard.

I did it this with the query.

```
Create table [SchemaName].[Tablename]
```

But I couldn't it with SSMS Databases -> [AdventureWorks] -> [Tables] -> (right-click) Table

I gave Table name `[Person].[Person2]` but It created in `dbo` schema and table name was wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are in the table designer, open the `Properties` window either from `View` menu and then `Properties Window` or just press <kbd>F4</kbd>)

In that dialog, you can change various properties of the table, including the schema.

Answer (score 0):

You need create schema first and then run your script as follow or as DavidG said using properties of the table to change the schema

```
CREATE SCHEMA [SchemaName]
GO
Create table [SchemaName].[Tablename](
    ID int,
    Name varchar(50)
)
GO
```

Comment: Why the call to `sp_executesql` here? Seems pointless. Also, I'm pretty sure op knows how to do this, they were asking about the IDE.

Answer (score -1):

On Postgres,

```
ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS SchemaName.Tablename
  SET SCHEMA AnotherSchemaName;
```